# php foreach loop nested increased repeating

Tags: php, foreach, nested-loops

I've got a loop nested in a loop. All of the data displays fine until I get to the second loop and the returned data keeps repeated. It gets to the point where songs of the items from the second loop gets repeated over 15 times.

item
-subitems

item
-subitems
-subitems

item
-subitems
-subitems
-subitems

item
-subitems
-subitems
-subitems 
-subitems

I was told to clear my loop but I'm sure how to do that. Any ideas?
here's a live example if need: view-source:http://mixtapemonkey.com/json

```
<?php 
include ("connection.php");

foreach($db->query("SELECT * FROM mixtapes WHERE year='2014' OR year = '2015' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 24") as $info) {

    echo "mixtape-".$info['id']," {\n";
        echo "\t\"id\" : \"".$info['id']."\",\n";
        echo "\t\"title\" : \"".$info['title']."\",\n";
        echo "\t\"name\" : \"".$info['name']."\",\n";
        echo "\t\"genre\" : \"".$info['genre']."\",\n";
        echo "\t\"year\" : \"".$info['year']."\",\n";
        echo "\t\"downloads\" : \"".$info['downloads']." Downloads\",\n";
        echo "\t\"thumb\" : \"http://mixtapemonkey.com/".$info['thumb']."\",\n";
        echo "\t\"songs\" : {\n";

            if ($handle = opendir("mixtapes/zip/".$info['id'])) {
                while (false !== ($entry = readdir($handle))) {
                    if ($entry != "mixtapes/zip/".$info['id'] && $entry != "mixtapes/zip/".$info['id']) {   


                            if ($newhandle = opendir("mixtapes/zip/".$info['id']."/".$entry)) {
                                while (false !== ($newentry = readdir($newhandle))) {
                                    if ($newentry != "mixtapes/zip/".$info['id']."/".$entry && $newentry != "mixtapes/zip/".$info['id']."/".$entry) {

                                       $ext = substr($newentry, strrpos($newentry, '.') + 1);
                                       if ($ext == "mp3" || $ext == "m4a")
                                        {
                                            $item = "mixtapes/zip/".$info['id']."/".$entry."/";
                                            $musicarray[] = $newentry;
                                            sort($musicarray);
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                                closedir($newhandle);
                            }

                    }
                }
                closedir($handle);
            }
            foreach ($musicarray as $song) {

            echo "\t\t\"track\" : \"http://mixtapemonkey.com/$item$song\",\n";
            }

        echo "\t}\n";
    echo "},\n\n";
}?>
```

Comment: If you dont know the depth of the sub-items, identify by any flag and do RECURSION.

Comment: @TNC what? Break it down for me. I'm new to a lot of this.

Comment: What i meant to say is you must have a clear vision of hierarchical tree formation on your sub items and traverse backwards. Definitely a RECURSION.

Comment: @TNC I just noticed that it's picking up the subitems and adding itself to the next subitems and that keeps repeating itself. view the source of mixtapemonkey.com/json - you wouldn't happen to know how to stop itself from doing that?

Comment: May be you can give a hit by Introducing a new function that returns all songs by information->id ($info['id']). and trying unset $musicarray.

Comment: @TNC Thanks for that last comment, really helped me out. I had this same issue, been debugging for the past 24 hours. I kept unsetting the last variable inside my foreach instead of the expression itself.

Answer (score 0):

I have a same problem also and I solved it to used php break after loop. So you can also try it to.

```
break;
```

Comment: That didn't help much. It just cuts my loop short.

Comment: a few places. the best I could get it do was only display a single -subitems. It stopped repeating but there are more than one item in the -subitems

Comment: Where you used break; on your code. Use break; at your code from where the repeating was started. If the break; stopping to display all items, re-position it, that means you cannot place it at right position to break.